# Can somebody help me so that I feel well about a word order

Tags: word-usage

Actually our educational system (about) English sucks. (Unfortunately), then granted, if you are given the below sentence,

> The study shows that current technology is very much close to producing robots .......

The "textbook" thing seems to be teaching us (or the asker in our Q&A site) that the word "much" is not here needed only because of the reason that the modifier of the adjective "close" should be only "very", the word "much" is redundant, so that it is not necessary here.

But it seems to me that explanation sucks and I can not help him/her. What is the viewpoint from native speakers?

Than you^^(m_m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much refers to quantity, it means a large amount. It’s not really possibly to have a large amount of “closeness”, at least in this context, as "close" is used as an adjective, and you can’t have an actual quantity of an adjective. We just modify if with words like “very”, “extremely”, etc., which modify degree, but not an actual quantity.

It is possible to say “much closer”, where “much” represents the difference in degree of closeness (presumed to be a quantitative difference) between this reference point and some other reference point (which would be in the past in your example).

Comment: I think I need to re-educate myself again. Thanks.